# Taskqueue for long running tasks in FLEXIBLE app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I am building an app using Flexible App Engine and Python3. In the standard appengine, if you needed to run a task that was longer than 60s, you could either use taskqueue, or the deferred library (an abstraction of taskqueue) which I have done successfully.

Flexible App Engine no longer supports appengine api which contains those functions. Instead, functionality is being migrated to the google-cloud library (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) instead (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app).

You can still access these appengine api functionalities by using the python-compat configuration, which is limited to Python 2.

Is there a way yet to run long tasks (queued) in Flexible Appengine without having to use the python-compat configuration?

Comment: what is the issue with google cloud library?

Comment: I dont see in the documentation any reference to TaskQueues. I must be missing something.....

Answer (score 0):

I had almost exactly the same problem [Increase time to run code for Google flexible app engine delaying DeadlineExceededError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667822/increase-time-to-run-code-for-google-flexible-app-engine-delaying-deadlineexceed)
, thinking that the problem was because of this deadlineexceedederror

but because this question asked about taskqueue etc, i thought maybe the answer is different. Actually, it boils down to the fact that in flexible environment with python3 this task running longer than 60s is not a constraint since all the code runs in docker containers. Thus, running a taskqueue etc might not even be needed.

It might be worth to check the `gunicorn`  entrypoint config. In the `app.yaml`file add the `-t` option and the number of seconds allowed before timeout.

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -t 120 -b :$PORT main:app
```

this solved the issue for me, now a code which was longer was running without an exit.